# Caching Mysql database for better performance

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-9.10

I'm using Amazon cloud and I've performance issue since the HDD is not located on my machine.
My database is small (~500MB) and I can afford to keep it all in my RAM. 
I do not want to keep queries in my RAM, i need all the tables there.

How can i do it?

Thanks,
Koby

P.S.
I'm using ubuntu server...

Answer (score 2):

You could add a caching layer. Memcached might be a good choice for you:

http://memcached.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can load indexes into cache; if you have small ISAM tables that are frequently queried, MySQL will probably load these into cache as well. Here is a good [Performance Wiki article](http://performancewiki.com/mysql-tuning.html) on MySQL tuning.

Comment: I do not have problem with the queries performance. its the time that takes to fetch all the data.